# c++ - Expression must have a pointer-to-object type

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox, compiler-errors, char

So I was following a tutorial on how to make a text box and get inputted text from it. I get the error 'Expression must have a pointer-to-object type' on the line where gwtstat, on the [0] part of &text[0]. Just a basic run down of my code incase anyone wants it, case 1: gets called when a 'Go' button is pressed next to the text box. TextBox is a HWND containing the text box, and the 'text' variable is of type char. Here is the code in whole:

```
switch (LOWORD(wParam)){
    case 1:
        int gwtstat = 0;

        gwtstat = GetWindowText(TextBox, &text[0], 20);
        ::MessageBox(hWnd, &text, &text, MB_OK);
}
```

So, I have looked through google and this website, but none of the answers have worked thus far.

EDIT::: Ok, just so yall have all the code, here's all the code that I use for the textbox:

```
HWND TextBox;
char text[20];
```

Where TextBox gets made: (inside DrawGLScene, called every frame)

```
if (testKey.isS()){
    TextBox = CreateWindow("EDIT", "", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 400, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Go", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 420, 10, 70, 20, hWnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use `[0]` on a variable of type `char`, did you mean to make it `char text[20]` ?

Comment: Hmmm, well it I changed 'text' to 'char text[20]', and it doesn't make a compile error, however the MessageBox doesn't display any text(just a blank MessageBox), so I'm guessing I'm not storing text correctly, or not getting it. And the above code worked perfectly in the tutorial I watched, no idea why it's not working for me

Comment: Post your complete text, where your `text` is defined. Plus post errors from the compiler.

Comment: @KirillKobelev Look at edit

Comment: change `::MessageBox(hWnd, &text, &text, MB_OK);` into `::MessageBox(hWnd, text, text, MB_OK);`

Comment: @Wimmel With that, there are no compile errors, but the MessageBox doesn't display any text.

Comment: @Xcox123 and what is the value of `gwtstat` after calling `GetWindowText`?

Comment: @Wimmel Ah, the value is 0... that'll be the problem xD But how come it's 0?

Comment: Try to use debugger.

Comment: @Wimmel So, I've looked at the msdn things, and it turns out that it's returning the TextBox title(so when it was "" it printed nothing, and when I change it to something like "hey" it prints hey, even though whats in the text box when I press Go isn't that). So yeah, whys it doing that?

Comment: You should try calling GetLastError(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx). The return value is 0 because either something failed copying the text, or the handle was invalid. If you use GetLastError you may get additional debug information. Alternatively, put a breakpoint on that line and jump into GetWindowText.

However, i'm pretty sure the problem is that you need to use wchar_t or a wide char for this function call (LPWSTR is a wide char type), or GetWindowTextA.